# Is the Feedback Assistant web address broken?

Tags: ios, bug-reporting

According to Apple: [Source](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)

> You can now submit developer feedback and file bug reports to Apple using the native Feedback Assistant app for iOS and Mac, or the Feedback Assistant website. When you file a bug, you’ll receive a Feedback ID to track the bug within the app or on the website. Feedback Assistant replaces Bug Reporter, which is no longer available.
>   The app requires iOS 12.4 beta, iOS 13 beta, or macOS Catalina beta, and will be supported in an upcoming beta of macOS 10.14.6. If you are on earlier releases, you can use feedbackassistant.apple.com.

I don't have 12.4 beta and don't really want to install it.  When I go to the website, *feedbackassistant.apple.com* I see this:

[image]

There is no way to login.  I keep getting brought back to this screen.  They claim in multiple places that we can submit bugs online at the [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) url if we don't have the new beta, but there is no way to do it.  I'd file the bug with them, but obviously I can't.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume the online Feedback Assistant is restricted to desktop only.

Comment: This is on my MacBook.

Comment: Is the Apple ID you're signed in to enrolled in the [Apple Beta Software Program](https://beta.apple.com/)? You may need to do it, even if you're not downloading a beta.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.